# Unable to select the correct coronavirus table data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, inspect-element

I am trying to scrape coronavirus data and push it on a tweet, but I am unable to figure out how to loop from a certain line

Source - https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZpNH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aoff.png)

```
results = soup.find(id = 'main_table_countries_today')
content = results.find_all('td')
print(entries.text)
for entries in content:
    print(entries.text.strip())
```

Ideally, I should get a non spaced list from the

But it seems I am getting data from the wrapper even though I specified table ID

[image: Image 1]

Image 1 = Is the extra data

Image 2 = is where I wanted to the non-spaced data to start

I need to place the countries names into a list based off this

The loop I am trying to run involves using the modulus operator based on line # as every 11th line a new country starts

```
        i = 1
    for entry in content:
        if i%11 == 1:
            countries.append(entry.text.strip())
        i += 1
        
    print(countries)
```

However, the above won't run because USA doesn't start at line 1 because of the extra space

Either I need to use a better ID  or figure out how to exclude the extra stuff at the top

Any suggestions? How do I go about this? Is there a better way than relying on the line # and modulus?

FYI - I am a beginner when it comes to python

Comment: Can you please elaborate in short what exactly you need? According to my understanding you require the country name only?

Comment: This is a good question. However, it would be better to share your effort result with the community. At least you provide an expected outcome or you can try to implement your own loop idea and share the resulting error or the unexpected result.

Comment: EDIT - Just added the source data link 
| So the first image is the expected output I wanted, the second is the issue I am having with the spaces | I actually need name of country, total cases, deaths and I am using a loop to place it all into a list, however I can't iteratively add it because my loop requires the exact line count between each country | Eg - USA is line 1 and 11 lines later the next country name starts with its details below it |

Comment: Just the usa line from ALL tab?

Comment: Table = main_table_countries_today, I want to scrap the countries name, total deaths and cases